# Changing IP address based on a list of predefined options

Tags: powershell

I want to change my static IP adresses for a specific network adapter. Changing the address works perfect with the NetIPAdress cmdlets. The only thing I want to add is something like a list to choose which address I want to use. So like press 1 for address scheme 1, press 2 for address scheme 2 and so on.

I had a list like that in a batch script I wrote some time ago. There the code looked like this:

```
    echo IP-AUSWAHLSKRIPT                                               
echo ================                                      
                                                                                    
echo IP Konfiguration                                                       
                                                                                    
echo 1 = Speedport  (feste IP .2.1)                                         
echo 2 = Fritz!Box  (feste IP .178.1)                                      
echo 3 = Lancom (feste IP .1.100)                          
echo 4 = Agfeo  (feste IP .100.1)                                                                                                                                           
                                                    
                                                                                    
echo 0 = Abbrechen                                                              



:auswahl
set /P wahl=Auswahl: 
if /i "%wahl%"=="1" goto:Speedport
if /i "%wahl%"=="2" goto:Fritz
if /i "%wahl%"=="3" goto:Lancom
if /i "%wahl%"=="4" goto:Agfeo
if /i "%wahl%"=="0" goto:exit
```

That's what I want with powershell. How to achieve that?

Comment: check out the `Read-Host`commandlet to get info from the commandline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is bordering on being too broad for this site.. but there is a really easy way to do this in PowerShell 3+ using [the `Out-GridView` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849920.aspx):

```
$ipChoices = @(
    '10.1.2.1' ,
    '10.1.2.2' ,
    '10.1.2.3' ,
    '10.1.2.4'
)

$ip = $ipChoices | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single
```

The list of IPs will come up in a Window, and it will allow you to choose one. That one will be returned to the pipeline (in this case, it will be assigned to the `$ip` variable).

Comment: neat, didn't know about this

Comment: @n3wjack it's pretty great, you can do multiple choice as well. I'd say like 90% of the time when I see people using Windows forms in PowerShell they could use this instead and simplify the whole script.

Comment: I've coded my own lists using write-host & read-host, but this is way easier :)